# Android create drawer like in whatsapp

Tags: android-studio

How can I create in android studio a drawer like in the picture? What is the name of this widget?

[image: whatsapp picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view shown above is a combination of normal toolbar at the top with the label whatsapp and an tablayout.
For full implementation and design. Use this link
[Tab layout with fragments](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/tab-layout-with-fragments)